# Is there any possible to create a custom menu in moodle

Tags: moodle

I am new to moodle. and i am using moodle 1.9.19+ what i want is to add a custom menu into the sidebare above the  Courses Menu.[image]

Is there any possible to do this.

Comment: 1.9 is very old, I would recommend upgrading to the latest version. Upgrade to the latest version of 1.9.x, then to 2.2.x, then to the current version which is 2.9.x

Comment: If i upgrade means is it possible to add a menu like my above example

Comment: If you will use the moodle over 2.x then you can customize the menu.